# Unable to cast Drawable to LayerDrawable in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable, classcastexception

I want to display notification badge on menu item. My code is

**onPrepareOptionsMenu()**

```
    int cartSize = MyCart.getCartSize();
    MenuItem cartItem = menu.findItem(R.id.toolbar_ic_cart);

    if (cartSize > 0) {
        LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) cartItem.getIcon();
        NotificationBadgeCount.setBadgeCount(this, icon, String.valueOf(cartSize));
    } else {
        cartItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_cart_empty);
    }
```

**menu/toolbar_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_ic_cart"
        android:title="Cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cart_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**@drawable/ic_cart_menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cart_full"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <!-- set a place holder Drawable so android:drawable isn't null -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_badge"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cart_empty" />

</layer-list>
```

This code was working fine for me. But after upgrading support libraries, I am getting error on all devices except Marshmallow

Error in following line

```
LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) cartItem.getIcon();
```

Error on Lollipop.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperLollipop cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
```

Error on Kitkat.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperKitkat cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
```

Comment: Check Your import for LayerDrawable,
It must be this - 

import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;

Comment: yes, it is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those wrapper classes all implement `DrawableWrapper`, from which you can get the original drawable:

```
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;
```

...

```
    LayerDrawable icon = null;
    Drawable drawable = cartItem.getIcon();
    if (drawable instanceof DrawableWrapper) {
        drawable = ((DrawableWrapper)drawable).getWrappedDrawable();
    }
    icon = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
```

Comment: can't find method getWrappedDrawable();

Comment: `import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;`

Comment: it was `android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;`

Comment: `import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;` doesn't exist, `android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;` doesn't work in my case

Comment: @CoolMind A lot has changed since I wrote this answer.  You're probably on the `androidx` packages now.  `DrawableWrapper` is marked `@hide`, so even though it's public, Google doesn't really want you using it.  You may need to write some version specific code (`if (BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE < VersionCodes.MARSHMALLOW)` etc. --- I forgot the exact syntax) to check whether to cast and which cast to use.  And you might need to go into the debugger on each version to find out the actual class names.  Worst case you may need to use reflection code to get at the `LayerDrawable`.

Comment: @krislarson, thank you! Sorry, I forgot that wrote an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53554149/2914140 for this case (`import android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;` or 
`android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.WrappedDrawable`).

Answer (score 1):

It is because `DrawableWrapperLollipop` extends `DrawableWrapperKitkat` and `DrawableWrapperKitkat` to some other older vesrion and so on.. But the parent class is `Drawable` and not `LayerDrawable`. That is the reason for exception.

Comment: can you suggest me a better solution for this issue