# ClassNotFoundException "android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper"

Tags: android, android-support-library

What can cause this error for class `DrawableWrapper` from the support lib?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.banyan.tasty-
1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: What is wrong in this question?

Comment: @Hari Prasath Can you please add more information. Your error could be related to the support library `dependencies` inside your `build.gradle`. Could you please add the relevant part of your configuration?

Answer (score 15):

Try updating your support library to 27.1.0.

Comment: Happens to me AFTER updating to 27.1.0

Answer (score 4):

Make sure all of your `"com.android.support:*"` dependencies are at the same version.

Looks like one of the support libraries uses something that is missing in the other one.

Answer (score 4):

i fixed same error updating version

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
```

To

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this exception in Android 5 and Android 4 users after removing `com.android.support-v13` from my `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}
```

I removed the above `exclude` configuration and no longer saw this crash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used support library version '27.0.2' for my project. It was working perfectly. However, when I copy & paste the project to different location and I opened in Android studio. That time, android studio added below line in build.gradle (path: MyProject/app/build.gradle)

**compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'**

Then I got the below exception.

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper" on path: DexPathList**

I removed the line from build.gradle (MyProject/app/build.gradle). Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer, and provide more context on why this answer works?

Answer (score 0):

`import android.support.v7.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;`

or

`import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.WrappedDrawable;` will help.

Also, when you use `Drawable inner = ((WrappedDrawable) drawable).getWrappedDrawable();`, you can add `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` above your method.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`enable D8`

if you using

`AS 3.1`