# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper;

Tags: java, android

**Application is running but when an alertdialog is opened then we get this error. It's been 4 days, didn't find any solution.**

```
  03-06 16:05:23.355 5505-5505/com.boltt.health E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper;
   at android.support.v7.widget.DrawableUtils.canSafelyMutateDrawable(DrawableUtils.java:149)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.tintDrawableUsingColorFilter(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:468)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.tintDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:294)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
   at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:85)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:192)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.getDelegate(AppCompatDialog.java:158)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:52)
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:97)
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:932)
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:957)
   at com.boltt.health.new_initialsetup.SignUp._openAlertDialog(SignUp.java:562)
   at com.boltt.health.new_initialsetup.SignUp.access$600(SignUp.java:66)
   at com.boltt.health.new_initialsetup.SignUp$2.onResponse(SignUp.java:332)
   at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6320)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1085)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:946)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.boltt.health-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.boltt.health-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.boltt.health-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
   at android.support.v7.widget.DrawableUtils.canSafelyMutateDrawable(DrawableUtils.java:149) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.tintDrawableUsingColorFilter(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:468) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.tintDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:294) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203) 
   at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:85) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:192) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.getDelegate(AppCompatDialog.java:158) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:52) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:97) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:932) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:957) 
   at com.boltt.health.new_initialsetup.SignUp._openAlertDialog(SignUp.java:562) 
   at com.boltt.health.new_initialsetup.SignUp.access$600(SignUp.java:66) 
   at com.boltt.health.new_initialsetup.SignUp$2.onResponse(SignUp.java:332) 
   at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6320) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1085) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:946)
```

Gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 18
        versionName "0.6"
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                useProguard true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
//            release {
//                minifyEnabled false
//                shrinkResources false
//                useProguard true
//                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//
//
//            }


    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}
configurations {
    compile5
    compile6
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    implementation 'com.minimize.library:seekbar-compat:0.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.CardinalNow:Android-CircleProgressIndicator:v0.2'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.amarjain07:StickyScrollView:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    // retrofit, gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'

    /*this library is for drawer layout. Please refer to the
                            * library page at : https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer*/
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.0.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    /*using for banding view*/

    //    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.6.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.0'

    /*Using for Graph*/
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'

    //    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'

    /*generic uses*/

    //    implementation("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2") {

    //        exclude module: 'shared'

    //    }

    //    compile5 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'

    //    compile6 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    // implementation 'com.github.jorgecastilloprz:fabprogresscircle:1.01@aar'

    // For networking
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'

    // For Bluetooth

    //    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:0.2.0'
    implementation ':validicmobile-release@aar'

    // implementation ':validicmobile-debug@aar'

    // You'll need to change this to point to your own jar.

    // Download: http://developer.samsung.com/health
    implementation fileTree(include: 'samsung-digital-health-healthdata-1.2.1.jar', dir: '../../../Common/libs')
    implementation files('libs/samsung-digital-health-healthdata-1.2.1.jar')

    //    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    // for round corners progress bar see in training lap analysis class
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.3.1'

    //    implementation 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'

    //for hash tags view
    implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.clarifai.clarifai-api2:core:2.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.2'

    //    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.0'

    /*used by suren
                * horizontal scrollable calendar used in plan section*/
    implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.1.7'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation files('libs/ute_sdk_v2.5.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ProtocolUtils.jar')
    implementation files('libs/greendao-2.1.0.jar')

    // Larva

    implementation files('libs/PGSDK_V2.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.tamir7.contacts:contacts:1.1.7'
    implementation 'io.ticofab.androidgpxparser:parser:1.1.0'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.1'
    implementation 'com.github.lespinsideg:SimplePanorama:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'

    //BolttCoin dependencies
    implementation 'com.dinuscxj:circleprogressbar:1.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Didn't find class "android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper" on path: DexPathList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026021/didnt-find-class-android-support-v4-graphics-drawable-drawablewrapper-on-path)

Comment: share your **`build.gradle`** with question

Comment: @NileshRathod i've added build.gradle

Comment: @user2176338 check my below ans

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/os/BuildCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-os-bui)

Comment: I've tried this solution but not solved my problem

Comment: This link may help to someone.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52480495/1404798

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are two possible duplicates of this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026021/classnotfoundexception-android-support-v4-graphics-drawable-drawablewrapper) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-os-bui). They both come to conclusion that upgrading your [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) to the latest version will fix the problem. Along with that, a clean and rebuild of the project and a restart of Android Studio could also help.

Comment: yes, you're right. I got it fixed after upgrading the Android Support Library and clean and rebuild of the project.

Comment: I hit this problem due to a different com.android.support version (different from what the rest of the app was using) sneaking into dependencies somewhere